# How can I stop suds from backing up in the drain line?

Tags: leak, drain

I have a 10 year old house with (probably) 2" vertical waste line inside the wall (plastic at top).  Lately we've noticed suds foaming out of the drain at the end of the rinse/spin cycle.  It does NOT leak when the machine is pumped out, only at the end of the cycle.  We have a 10 year old Amana top-loading washer, and are using the recommended amount of Purex liquid detergent.  The washer has a corrugated flexible drain hose, with 1 1/8" diameter end that fits 5" into the waste pipe.

I tried to snake the waste line but the snake will not make the bend at the bottom of the wall (about 3-3.5').  I also tried a clean-out that is about 1' from the drain line (the snake went in a good 15' and came out clean).  I suppose the cleanout is in the vent line, upstream of the drain line.

It seems the drain takes the water (both wash & rinse) but then fills up with suds at the end of the spin cycle.  Other than reducing the amount of detergent, is there anything we can do?

Comment: If you can't get the snake to go down the drain, I'd try a different snake or technique until one does or you find a clog.

Comment: There are low-suds detergents. In general, suds are only useful when hand-washing anyway, since their going flat indicates that you're using up the surfactant and need more to fully dissolve the oils you're trying to remove. In a machine, where you aren't watching the process, they serve no purpose.